# Connect an Android tablet to ethernet

Tags: usb, networking, samsung-galaxy-tab

I use tablet with Android in a professional environment and the it department doesn't accept to install wifi.

My tablet need to synchronise with CSV file on a LAN share.

I'm looking for solutions. Is it possible to connect a tablet on ethernet (possibly with builtin firmware)? If yes, which model?

I looked for solutions and I found some interesting links:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1274656 / a pack to add ethernet support to Asus
- http://www.sosandroid.fr/forumAndroid/topic1980.html Iconia Tab a500
- http://discuz-android.blogspot.fr/2011/07/step-by-step-to-enable-lan-access-for.html Motorola Xoom

Does someone have experience with this? I prefer avoid root my tablet or use a custom firmware or launch some custom command when connected to the network, but if no Android tablet come with this feature built in, I would be willing to root it.

Alternate solution:  connect the tablet to the PC with USB and access the LAN share located on the computer (it was possible with Windows Mobile) and maybe access the whole network.

I own a Galaxy Tab 8.9 and the best would be to find a solution with that tablet.

Comment: What about connecting a laptop to the LAN by ethernet, then hosting a private wireless connection on the laptop that your Android device can use? Once you enable connection sharing in Windows, the connected Android device can access all LAN shares. *Just make sure the hosted wireless network is encrypted strongly and secured with a password.* You can also host a **Bluetooth** network on your laptop (a little harder to set up, but shorter range) or simply use USB pass-through.

Comment: I'm looking for USB Ethernet for Samsung Note 10.1 2014 edition and this looks possible:
http://www.bobjgear.com/which-tablets-support-ethernet.html

Comment: Confirmed! :) After ROOT and lite network configuration we run LAN over USB OTG cable with Edimax EU-4207 adapter.
Samsung SM-P600, Android 4.4.2 Kitkat.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that device https://sites.google.com/site/bobjgear/Android-Ethernet-Adapter

I think it is the solution. If you have some specific tablet like Xoom you can use ethernet with that specific adapter

Comment: You've mentioned that you own a Samsung Galaxy Tab, and you've provided a link marked in red where it reads: **THIS ADAPTER DOES NOT WORK WITH: Samsung Tablets' accessory 30-pin-to-USB adapter is not compatible.**. Can you elaborate on how does this answered your question?

Comment: The customer can buy the product I specify. (In the beginning of my question : "if yes, which model ?". And the best would be to use Galaxy Tab 8.9 but it wasn't mandatory. Sorry if it wasn't clearly specified.

Answer (score 6):

Your [Galaxy tab 8.9 connectivity specifications](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/GT-P7310MAAXAR-specs) don't include wired Ethernet:

```
╔════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ Connectivity           ║                      ║
╠════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ WiFi                   ║ WiFi 802.11 a/b/g/n  ║
║ USB                    ║ USB 2.0 H/S          ║
║ Bluetooth              ║ Bluetooth 3.0        ║     
╚════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

To solve your issue a simple USB to Ethernet adapter would suffice, but as pointed out on the first comment on this answer, your device uses a proprietary connector, so an initial adapter is required:

[Samsung Galaxy Tab™ USB & SD Connection Kit](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab-accessories/EPL-1PLRBEGSTA)

[image]

Another pertinent issue as mentioned, relating an Android driver and the support for USB to Ethernet adapters, but this [Plugable USB 2.0 10/100 Ethernet Adapter (ASIX AX88772 Chipset)](http://plugable.com/products/usb2-e100/), as mentioned on their [support forum](http://support.plugable.com/plugable/topics/usb_to_ethernet_adapter_for_a_7_android_tablet_need_a_driver_please) might help you.

[image]

From Amazon:

[Plugable USB 2.0 to 10/100 Fast Ethernet LAN Network RJ45 Adapter (ASIX AX88772 chipset)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00484IEJS)

Comment: The Galaxy Tab line doesn't use regular USB type A ports, they have a proprietary connector. The above will not work on that device without some kind of adapter, and even if it could plug in there's really no guarantee that Android would have the drivers to support it (as the links in the OP's question illustrate).

Comment: well I understood that I can use an adapter to convert the samsung proprietary port and I understood that I can compile a new driver but it sound like complicated for my need ...

Answer (score 3):

I am also facing the same problem, and here is what I discovered until now. Some tablets do allow an ethernet port (they even have the port itself). Mostly you will have to buy an ethernet adpter (RJ45) to use it through the USB port, and an mini (or micro) USB adapter to connect to the tablet. Be careful to buy the RJ45 adapter that fits to the tablet's chipset. Otherwise, it will not work.

Those are the ones I know:

- Ainol Fire dual core (not rooted - only w/ original firmware): out of stock at the manufacturer
- Onda V972 (still under manufacture's portfolio)

Hope this helps.